# Page Cache not Fully Released

Tags: linux, file-management, cache, rss, memory-management

I tried to release all **page cache** pages. First, I checked its **current size**. `cat /proc/meminfo|head` shows:

```
MemTotal:       11703912 kB
MemFree:         5637568 kB
MemAvailable:    7114944 kB
Buffers:          136304 kB
Cached:          3184944 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2760572 kB
Inactive:        1424344 kB
Active(anon):    2271112 kB
Inactive(anon):   251312 kB
```

It is `3,184,944 KB`. Then, I tried to **clear** page cache using the following command:

```
sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

`cat /proc/meminfo|head` changed to this:

```
MemTotal:       11703912 kB
MemFree:         6722340 kB
MemAvailable:    7062480 kB
Buffers:            3408 kB
Cached:          2271332 kB
SwapCached:            0 kB
Active:          2418432 kB
Inactive:        1938232 kB
Active(anon):    2277092 kB
Inactive(anon):  1535468 kB
```

Almost `1 GB` is released. *Why is around `2 GB` still **locked** in memory?*

I also processed `sudo lsof` output and the **total** size was `1,586,536,501 B`. Note that, this is the **total** size and `RSS` should be **smaller**. This is still about `1 GB` **smaller** than the size of page cache cotents. *Am I **missing** something? **Any** guesses/suggestions is appreciated!*

---

**UPDATE:**

Let's assume that all `2 GB` is needed by live processes. Reading `2 GB` from disk (at least in my slow hard disk) should take some time. But page cache size is refreshed to `2 GB`, almost, immediately.

If we assume that open files in live processes will be immediately reclaimed (i.e., will not be released and re-read from disk), then the following should not occur:

*`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11510.0` is in page cache and applying `vmtouch -v` on the file results in:*

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11510.0
[OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOoOOOOOoOOOOOoOoOOOOOOoo   oOOO] 257/284

           Files: 1
     Directories: 0
  Resident Pages: 257/284  1M/1M  90.5%
         Elapsed: 9.1e-05 seconds
```

*I opened the `libcairo` and, as a consequence, `vmtouch` reported `100%` residency. Then I released page cache. `240` out of `284` pages were resident (instead of `284` out of `284`). This means that the pages were actually accessed from disk. Otherwise (i.e., if the release operation was ignored), residency would remain `284` out of `284`.*

Perhaps, some pages are **locked** in memory?!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? This sounds very much like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Comment: I want to estimate the **intensity** of page cache memory access in **idle system**, both in terms of *bandwidth* and *size* of the working set.

Answer (score 1):

You can't release all the pages in the page cache without killing all the processes running on the system.   The page cache at least in part holds pages backing the portions running processes that come from the disk, like executable pages and libraries.

Or, to put it another way, you can release all the page cache, but some of it will be instantly picked back up, as the pages are still needed.

When you request the pages to be released, the release action doesn't erase the pages or immediately mark them as free.  It marks them as immediately available.  And then they are immediately marked as used, as what is in memory still needs them.

So when you read the file in, all the pages are now in memory.
Then you tell the system to release the pages, and all the pages are released, but the ones actually being used are reclaimed immediately, likely before the actual flush occurs.  The ones that you forced to be read in remain released.

Comment: You mean the *relatively idle system* reads around `2 GB` from **files** in **less than a second**?

Comment: How do you interpret the results obtained from the `lsof` output? Also reading `2 GB` from **harddisk**  should be *time-consuming*! But the value is updated in **less than a second** (**even not visible**).

Comment: Disks can do 6G/sec, so why is 2G going to be time consuming?  Also, just because you released the pages, doesn't mean they are wiped from memory.  They can be instantly reclaimed without re-reading from disk, especially when something is still using them.  This is why you can't release them without killing things.

Comment: My idle Ubuntu system has ~400 processes, all sleeping.  Those use memory.  They have associated shared libraries and executables.  All of that is in page cache, even if they are not using any cpu.

Comment: The harddisk in my Laptop is not that fast. So you say that reclaiming is done without rereading? In other words, you say that the release action is ignored for live processes? This seems reasonable, but, the disk should not be completely ignored.Please have a look at the updated question.

Comment: To be sure the pages are not being reread so quickly, you need to check disk statistics, possibly with something like iostat.

Comment: So, you're saying that data are marked to be released, and then released. Meanwhile, if data are used (i.e., accessed before the actual release action is done), the marking will be canceled for them. Therefore, they won't be released and re-read from disk (unlike the pages forced to be read). Could you point me the relevant sources in kernel?

Comment: Does this mean that at least `2 GB` will be accessed in a small period in a relatively idle system? In a GUI-less environment (*root terminal* in `recovery mode`), `Intel PCM Tools` shows around `2 GB/s` memory access, which is also true in GUI environment. Both are, relatively, idle. In the former case, `Perf` shows `90%` of instructions are in kernel mode. Therefore, I conclude that in both cases few memory accesses should be caused by user apps and targeted at page cache, as page cache is mainly accessed by user level code. `2 GB/s` for idle system with user level code seems *unlikely*!

Comment: 2 GB/s is not required to have all these pages marked to be kept -- you only need to touch a single byte per page.  And unless the entire process is to be swapped out, you might not need to touch any bytes to retain the ones it is using.